# read values inside text file and store into array in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file which is contained 1000 lines. each line included 10 values as follow:

```
value1  value2  value3  ... value8  value9  value10
value11 value12 value13 ... value18 value19 value20
```

In Fortran I used

> read(FileID,FileFormat) (acc(ii),ii=1,npt)

to read values and store them in an array acc = [value1, value2, ... value19 value20].

Is there any way to do same thing in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your text file be test.txt, this is as simple as this.
It will replace any newline character with space and convert the string into array

```
val = open("test.txt").read()
arr = val.replace('\n',' ').split(" ")
print(arr)
```